# How to use file I/O c++

Tags: c++, file-io

First I'm trying to create a file and write to it, it is not letting me use the "<<" to write to the file, and the second part I'm trying to read the data from the file but I'm not certain that is the right way since I want to save the data into the objects so I can use the objects later in my program. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
void Employee::writeData(ofstream&)
{
  Employee joe(37," ""Joe Brown"," ""123 Main ST"," ""123-6788", 45, 10.00);
  Employee sam(21,"\nSam Jones", "\n 45 East State", "\n661-9000",30,12.00);
  Employee mary(15, "\nMary Smith","\n12 High Street","\n401-8900",40, 15.00);

  ofstream outputStream;
  outputStream.open("theDatafile.txt");
  outputStream << joe << endl << sam << endl << mary << endl;
  //it says that no operator "<<"matches this operands, operands types are std::ofstream<<employee
  outputStream.close();
  cout<<"The file has been created"<<endl;
}

void Employee::readData(ifstream&)
{
  //here im trying to open the file created and read the data from it, but I'm strugguling to figure out how to read the data and save it into de class objects.
  string joe;
  string sam;
  string mary;

  ifstream inputStream;
  inputStream.open("theDatafile.txt");
  getline(inputStream, joe);
  getline(inputStream, sam);
  getline(inputStream, mary);
  inputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: You need to define an `operator <<` for `Employee`.

Comment: @carlpett: `<<` is for output, `>>` for input

Comment: @Ken: Wow, I must tired. No more SO for tonight...

Comment: Does your class `Employee` overwrite `operator <<` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are receiving is because you need to define an output operator for the employee class.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& _os, const Employee& _e) {
  //do all the output as necessary: _os << _e.variable;
}
```

It is a good idea to also implement the input operator:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& _is, Employee& _e) {
  //get all the data: _is >> _e.variable;
}
```

You should make these friend functions to your class Employee:

```
class Employee {
  public:
    //....
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& _os, const Employee& _e);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& _is, Employee& _e);
    //....
}
```

Comment: @pipin1289, I tried adding the operator to my function, now it says there are too many parameter for the operator function.

Comment: @GamalielTellezOrtiz You should make it a `friend` function of the class and still define it outside.